# Rails: in an array of classes how to discern whether each has a table?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I've got an array of classes I need to loop through. How can I exit the loop if the class doesn't inherit from `ActiveRecord::Base` (i.e., no table)?

```
classes_array.each do |klass|
  return if klass.doesnt_have_a_table
  ...
end
```

Not sure how to implement that. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `superclass` method, like this:

```
classes_array.each do |klass|
    break unless klass.superclass == ActiveRecord::Base
    ...
end
```

Comment: `return` will not break out of the loop

Comment: Yeap, @infused, sorry, I only checked the condition, pasted the rest. I fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

Check to see if the model's ancestors includes `ActiveRecord::Base` and call break if it does not:

```
classes_array.each do |klass|
  break unless klass.ancestors.include?(ActiveRecord::Base)
end
```